Grouping parts of one CELL with contents within another CELL
Here is an Excel example of what I need to solve preferably using a VBA Code.
Cell A1 contains Z002,Z003,Z004,Z006,Z007
Cell B1 Contains Z200
Cell C1 Contains Z002,Z003,Z004,Z005,Z006,Z007,Z008
B1 is a single value defining the values A1
All values in Cell A1 must be contained in Cell C1 for the result to be true
Cell D1 result would then be, Z200,Z005,Z008
To take that to the next row where it is not true
Cell A2 contains Z002,Z003,Z004,Z006,Z007
Cell B2 Contains Z200
Cell C2 Contains Z002,Z003,Z005,Z006,Z007
Cell D2 Result would be Z002,Z003,Z005,Z006,Z007
In this 2nd example all the values in A2 are not contained within C2 so the result in D2 would just be C2 again.
I want a formula in column D that refers to the values in A, B & C to get the desired result.
The formula in D# can be a Macro as such, =Group(A#,B#,C#)
So D returns the changes if A is part of the group in C, else just return C
Thanks in Advance
mbart67
I tried this,
Function Group(valuesA As String, valuesB As String, valuesC As String) As String
    Dim arrA() As String
    Dim arrB() As String
    Dim arrC() As String
    Dim Unmatched As String
    Dim i As Integer, Found As Boolean
    
    ' Split each string by commas into arrays
    arrA = Split(valuesA, ",")
    arrB = Split(valuesB, ",")
    arrC = Split(valuesC, ",")
    
    ' Check if all values in A are contained in C
    For i = LBound(arrA) To UBound(arrA)
        Found = False
        Dim j As Integer
        For j = LBound(arrC) To UBound(arrC)
            If Trim(arrA(i)) = Trim(arrC(j)) Then
                Found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        ' If a value in A is not found in C, return the entire C list
        If Not Found Then
            Group = valuesC
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' If all values in A are found in C, combine unmatched B and C
    Unmatched = valuesB
    
    ' Check for values in C that are not in A
    For i = LBound(arrC) To UBound(arrC)
        Found = False
        For j = LBound(arrA) To UBound(arrA)
            If Trim(arrC(i)) = Trim(arrA(j)) Then
                Found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        ' If not found in A, add to the unmatched list
        If Not Found Then
            If Len(Unmatched) > 0 Then
                Unmatched = Unmatched & "," & arrC(i)
            Else
                Unmatched = arrC(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    Group = Unmatched
End Function


Trying to understand what you want: In your second example, you say that "all the values in A2 are not contained within C2", but A2 and C2 both contain Z002, Z003, Z006 and Z007. Also Cell B2 seems to be ignored, while Cell B1 was included. Are you able to edit you question to clarify, please?

Hi mdmay74,
The 2nd example was to show when ALL values in A2 are NOT contained within C2, the end result remains as C2.
The value in B is the shorter single value of what is contained in A. Hence why in the 1st example, where ALL the values in A1 are contained within C1, the result is Z200 (which is the single version of A1 as defined in B1),Z005,Z008 (Which are the 2 strings in C1 no defined in A1).  ie D1 = Z200,Z005,Z008 and in the 2nd example D2=C2 because A2 is NOT a complete subset of C2. Hope that clarifies a little.

VBA solution:
Function CheckValues(A As String, B As String, C As String) As String
    Dim arrA() As String
    Dim arrC() As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim allContained As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim found As Boolean
    
    arrA = Split(A, ",")
    arrC = Split(C, ",")
    allContained = True
    
    ' Check if all values in A are contained in C
    For i = LBound(arrA) To UBound(arrA)
        found = False
        For j = LBound(arrC) To UBound(arrC)
            If arrA(i) = arrC(j) Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not found Then
            allContained = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    If allContained Then
        ' If all values in A are contained in C, find values not in A
        result = B
        For j = LBound(arrC) To UBound(arrC)
            found = False
            For i = LBound(arrA) To UBound(arrA)
                If arrC(j) = arrA(i) Then
                    found = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            If Not found Then
                result = result & "," & arrC(j)
            End If
        Next j
    Else
        ' If not all values in A are contained in C, return C
        result = C
    End If
    
    CheckValues = result
End Function


It is easy enough to do it in VBA but I think it's an overkill. Can be pretty easily handled with a formula I think:

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TEXTSPLIT(A2, ","), TEXTSPLIT(C2, ","), 0))),
    TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, B2, FILTER(TEXTSPLIT(C2, ","), ISNA(MATCH(TEXTSPLIT(C2, ","), TEXTSPLIT(A2, ","), 0)))),
    C2)


Build String Depending on Whether a Delimited List Is a Subset of Another

Function GetGroupList( _
    ByVal List As String, _
    ByVal Sublist As String, _
    ByVal ListTitle As String, _
    Optional ByVal ListDelimiter As String = ",", _
    Optional ByVal TitleDelimiter As String = ": ") _
As String
    
    ' Validate the inputs.
    
    Dim Result As String
    
    If Len(ListDelimiter) = 0 Then Result = vbNullString: GoTo WriteResult
    If Len(ListTitle) = 0 Then Result = vbNullString: GoTo WriteResult
    If Len(List) = 0 Then Result = vbNullString: GoTo WriteResult
    If Len(Sublist) = 0 Then Result = List: GoTo WriteResult
    If Len(List) < Len(Sublist) Then Result = List: GoTo WriteResult
    
    ' Split the lists into arrays.
    
    Dim ArrSub() As String: ArrSub = Split(Sublist, ListDelimiter)
    Dim ArrList() As String: ArrList = Split(List, ListDelimiter)
    
    ' Determine whether 'Sublist' is a subset of 'List'.
    
    Dim IsSubset As Boolean
    
    With Application
        IsSubset = (.Count(.Match(ArrSub, ArrList, 0)) = .CountA(ArrSub))
    End With
     
    ' Build the result.
     
    Dim Indices() As Variant, i As Long
     
    If IsSubset Then
        Indices = Application.Match(ArrList, ArrSub, 0)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Indices)
            If IsError(Indices(i)) Then
                Result = Result & ListDelimiter & ArrList(i - 1)
            End If
        Next i
        If Len(Result) = 0 Then
            Result = ListTitle
        Else
            Result = ListTitle & TitleDelimiter & _
                Right(Result, Len(Result) - Len(ListDelimiter))
        End If
    Else
        Result = List
    End If
    
WriteResult:
    GetGroupList = Result

End Function

